# angular-ui-router 1.0.x: event.preventDefault & event.defaultPrevented alternative

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, angularjs-1.6

I just replaced the `$stateChangeStart` with `$transitions.onStart`

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, ...){
     e.preventDefault();
     // other code goes here...
});
```

to

```
$transitions.onStart({}, function(tras){
     // need a code equivalent to e.preventDefault
     // need a code to identify event.defaultPrevented 
     // other code goes here...

     // get parent states
     _o.util.getAncestorStates(toState.name, true).reverse()
        .forEach(function (state) {
           // certain condition to call event.preventDefault()

           if(event.defaultPrevented) {....}
     });
});
```

and I guess, we can prevent the transition by adding `return $q.reject()` instead of `e.preventDefault()` but I could not understand how the code below `return $q.reject()` would execute.

Also, how can I replace `event.defaultPrevented`?

I think should be done something on the `transition.promise` but not clear.

I am sorry, I can't understand the official doc - https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/ easily. Can anybody help me finding out a better explanation or the replacement for the above code?

Comment: I think you can just `return false` from `.onStart` to cancel the transition..

Comment: ok, I just added more snippet to understand why do I need `event.defaultPrevented` - I process all parent states & on a certain condition I call `event.preventDefault` & I check `event.defaultPrevented` for any other parent state.

Comment: With promise chains, code in subsequent `.then` blocks are skipped if a previous block cancels. An `onStart` handler will never be called if a previous handler cancels a transition. `event.defaultPrevented` will never be `true` in an `onStart` handler. Instead the `onError` handler chain gets called and those blocks will only be called if  and only if `event.defaultPrevented` is true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can choose one of these two options depend on your logic:

- Since ***angular-ui-router 1.0.3*** you can use [`$transition.abort()`](https://ui-router.github.io/ng2/docs/latest/classes/transition.transition-1.html#abort). Cleaner choice if you have to abort state change after an async call.

  ```
  $transitions.onStart({}, function($transition) {
      $transition.abort();
      //more code...
  });
  ```
- Also, as @tanmay says in comments, you can use a simple `return false` to cancel it. This will work in non stable versions too (***1.0.0.beta and 1.0.0.rc***). ([Check it in ui-rooter docs](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/modules/transition.html#hookresult))

  ```
  $transitions.onStart({}, function($transition) {
      //code ...
      return false;
  });
  ```