# $urlRouterProvider.rule full in circular when do preventDefault in $stateChangeStart

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am working on an Angularjs SPA with [angular-ui-route](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) v0.3.1.

Recently applied [rule()](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#rule-for-custom-url-handling) to allow case insensitive urls...

```
    $urlRouterProvider.rule(function ($injector, $location) {
        //what this function returns will be set as the $location.url
        var path = $location.path(), normalized = path.toLowerCase();
        if (path != normalized) {
            //instead of returning a new url string, I'll just change the $location.path directly so I don't have to worry about constructing a new url string and so a new state change is not triggered
            $location.replace().path(normalized);
        }
        // because we've returned nothing, no state change occurs
    });
```

also i am listening to `$stateChangeStart` event to check if the user is not logged in and redirect him to login page

```
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                if (!('data' in toState) || !('access' in toState.data)) {
                    messageHandler.show({
                        message: 'Access undefined for this state',
                        messageType: messageHandler.messageTypes.error
                    });
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
                else
                    if (!auth.authorize(toState.data.access)) {
                        event.preventDefault();// this line cause my circular issue

                        if (!auth.isLoggedIn()) {
                            var redirectState = toState.name;
                            auth.login( redirectState);
                        }
                        else {

                            messageHandler.show({
                                message: 'Seems like you tried accessing a route you do not have access to : ' + toState.name,
                                messageType: messageHandler.messageTypes.warning
                            });
                            $state.go('unauthorized');
                        }
                    }

            });
```

The problem is that the **role** filter is do normalize the url, them when doing  **event.preventDefault()** in `$stateChangeStart` event, the normalized url is being cancelled and the loop occurs again.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "any help" -> to use [$transitions service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43888603/angular-ui-router-1-0-x-event-preventdefault-event-defaultprevented-alternati)

Comment: is there a way to fix without upgrade into 1.0.x?

Comment: found out better way to solve it which is using `$urlMatcherFactoryProvider` provider in the config:

$urlMatcherFactory.caseInsensitive(true);